# Cant print Headers in karate feature file

Tags: karate

I am using karate (https://github.com/intuit/karate) for some API testing and have a test with invalid headers. I would like to print the headers out while debugging, to make sure everything is being set properly. This is how i set and attempt to print, but nothing is working. I can find anything on it in the documentation. Does anybody know? Much appreciated!!

```
Given path '/metadata/project/' + projectID + '/graph/' + graphID
And headers { Authorization: 'INVALID', Content-Type:#(headerValue)}
And request graphJSON
* print headers // prints nothing
* print requestHeaders  // prints nothing
* print requestHeader   // prints nothing
* print header // prints nothing
When method put
Then status 401 // this passes, so i know the header is being set
* print response // prints correctly
* print responseHeaders //prints correctly
```

How to print the headers that will be sent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm surprised you don't see the headers in the console and in the log `target/karate.log` - this should happen by default and you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#logging

Also refer to the docs for the built-in variables instead of trying to guess them: https://github.com/intuit/karate#responseheaders

But if you really want to print the actual headers sent (very rarely needed), you can do this:

```
* print 'headers:', karate.prevRequest.headers
```

EDIT: in Karate 1.3.0 onwards this is recommended:

```
* print karate.response.headers
```

This is explained here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-prevrequest

EDIT: I noticed you may be making a common mistake, when you have hyphens in the JSON key - you need to use string quotes:

```
And headers { Authorization: 'INVALID', 'Content-Type': '#(headerValue)' }
```

And yes, this is explained in the docs as well.

Comment: i was expecting the info to be in the https://github.com/intuit/karate#headers section

Comment: Also the content-type seems to be working anyways, but i will check the docs on that and probably change it as per your suggestion anyways. thanks!